# Hold two microcontrollers in reset at turn-off with one DPDT power switch?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, reset

I want to use the second switch to ensure that two micros are both held in reset when the switch is off.  They use different supplies and one sometimes also resets the other, so I want to use MOSFETs.  I also don't want to burn too many microamps when on.  So far I have this:

[image: reset circuit schematic]

The 1-2-3 contacts of switch SW1 hold MOSFET gates near ground when the device is on, and the pull-up resistor R1 takes it high when off, turning on the MOSFETs and holding the ucs in reset.

Questions:

1. Is R1 too big at 2M?  I think in this application which only handles a single switch event (with bounces though) and not 500 kHz switching or something it doesn't matter.  I would use 3M if it's safe.  Even if the MOSFET behaved badly during transition I think it wouldn't matter once things stabilize?
2. On the general idea that sharp edges are bad when not needed I've added a 100 pF capacitor C3 giving R1-C3 time constant 0.2 ms.  This is about an order of magnitude less than the time constant for C2 at max load, so I think the ucs should always be safely in reset before C2 runs out of juice during a turn-off event.  But maybe this capacitor is pointless or potentially bad?
3. R2 is just to limit the discharge from C3 during bounce events during turn-off.  It probably isn't even needed?
4. Anything else obviously wrong or sub-optimal?

Comment: My two cents would be check out the MAX16054. It’s this super handy IC that controls on/off with debounce and stuff, so might be able to make this a whole heap simpler. Hope this helps!

Comment: MAX16054 looks nice one issue is I need to control both resets, but also allow one to be pulled low independent of the other.  So it looks like I would need two of them which is getting a little expensive/power hungry at ~$2/14uA

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to control the resets on two MCUs, but have the ability to select which one (or both) gets reset, with one switch?

Comment: When off switch isn't on, I want them both held in reset via the MOSFETs.  But when it is on, uc1 sometimes also needs to reset uc2.  So the reset lines can't be tied together.  I looked for a 3PDT (three switches that all switch together) but it seems they're rare and expensive hence the MOSFET fun.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if you've already tried this, but from what you've described, it sounds like you should be able to pull it off with just a switch and p-type mosfet like this.

That way, uC1 can trigger a reset with its GPIO, and not reset itself. Definitely throw pull-ups in there too, I've left them out for the sake of showing the principle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbBlxg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>